# Saving the results of a SELECT Stored procedure ASP.NET Entity Framework

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, stored-procedures

I am searching all over the web for an answer to this question and I have come up short.  I have a simple stored procedure that selects columns from a view, I would like to save this data in a Model in my program.  However, when I call the stored procedure it has a return type of ObjectResult, so I have been trying to implement this but I am at a loss for what datatype to use in my model.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetPartnerCompanyRelationships]
    @inputCoid INT
AS
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    -- Insert statements for procedure here
    SELECT [CoId]
      ,[CompanyName]
      ,[CompanyId]
      ,[PartnerCoId]
      ,[PartnerCompanyName]
      ,Count(*) as DocumentTotal
  FROM vwDocuments 
  where coid = @inputCoid and DocumentType = 'order' and PartnerCoId <> @inputCoid
  group by [CoId]
      ,[CompanyName]
      ,[CompanyId]
      ,[PartnerCoId]
      ,[PartnerCompanyName]
union all
SELECT [CoId]
      ,[CompanyName]
      ,[CompanyId]
      ,[PartnerCoId]
      ,[PartnerCompanyName]
      ,Count(*) as DocumentTotal
  FROM vwDocuments 
  where PartnerCoId = @inputCoid and DocumentType = 'order' and CoId <> @inputCoid
  group by [CoId]
      ,[CompanyName]
      ,[CompanyId]
      ,[PartnerCoId]
      ,[PartnerCompanyName]

END
```

The procedure just selects these columns.

I want my model to hold this data so I can reference it in a View and build a table from it but the issue is saving this data.

```
public ObjectResult GetPartnerCompanyRelationships(int coid)
        {
            using (var context = LTPortalEntities.getEntities())
            {
                ObjectResult x = context.GetPartnerCompanyRelationships(coid);
                return x;
            }
        }
```

This is what I have tried in my datahelper class, and in my Controller:

```
var companyList = _da.GetPartnerCompanyRelationships(coid);
                    foreach (vwDocument item in companyList)
                    {
                        MyDashBoard.CompanyList.Add(item);
                    }
```

If this is vague please let me know what to include, this is my first shot at getting information with a stored procedure.

One of the other issues I have encountered is trying to ORDER BY with a select from a view, my procedure didn't like that very much.  So I am wondering if creating a function would be easier? If so, how to get that into the edmx.

Comment: Well I think I found the issue, since I cannot map my procedure to an entity because of the Count() I am hitting a wall.

Comment: Try it as a table valued function.

Comment: I tried defining a table valued function, but I could not figure out how to import it into the edmx.  When I created it in the database it did not show up under storedprocedure/functions update menu.

Comment: I think table valued functions only work with entity framework 5+

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was not aware that the stored procedure added an object to my data class
I simply had to update my Model with:

```
 public List<GetPartnerCompanyRelationships_Result> DashboardCompanyList { get; set; }
```

Update my DBHelper with:

```
public List<GetPartnerCompanyRelationships_Result> GetPartnerCompanyRelationships(int coid)
        {
            using (var context = Entities.getEntities())
            {
                var x = context.GetPartnerCompanyRelationships(coid);
                return x.ToList();
            }
        }
```

And call the method from my controller:

```
MyDashBoard.DashboardCompanyList = _da.GetPartnerCompanyRelationships(coid);
```

This allowed me to use all of the complex data in my model.